# Subclassed form doesn't render customized input field in Django

Tags: django

I have a subclassed form which I want to render a custom `max` attribute on the input field. However, it doesn't return any form instance in the view and thus doesn't render any input field either:

```
# views.py
..
        custom_max_attribute = qs_aggregates['total_equity']
        print(custom_max_attribute) # prints 4000

        withdraw_form = WithdrawForm(custom_max_attribute)
        print(withdraw_form) # prints nothing
..
```

```
# template

..
<div class="field-wrapper">
    <div class="field-title">Set your Amount</div>
    <div class="withdraw-input-field">{{ withdraw_form.withdraw_amount }}</div> <!-- isnt rendered -->
</div>
..
```

```
# forms.py

class WithdrawForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A form to withdraw available funds from Farena to the users bank account
    """
    def __init__(self, custom_max_attribute, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(self, custom_max_attribute, *args, **kwargs)

        withdraw_amount = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': 1, 'max': custom_max_attribute, 'step': 0.01}))
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a workaround**, works for me but I see that you are working with withdrawals so you may need to *implement some additional validation on form submission*.

Basically. You can set custom attributes in JS, add class to the input in forms.py like this

```
widgets ={
   'name'    :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'shippForm'}),
   'withdraw':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'shippForm'}),
}
```

and then you can just

```js
    var form_fields = document.getElementsByClassName('shippForm')
    form_fields[0].placeholder='{% trans "Name"  %}';
    form_fields[1].max='2115';
```

the max (**2115**) can be taken from context/database etc so you can check if user did some frontend shenanigans